# composer ошибка при добавлении токена из github

Tags: php, composer

Я пытаюсь в composer.json установить **config github-oauth.github.com <токен>**

**1**.  Если  ввожу команду так, как указанно в официальной документации (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md):

> composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <мой_токен>

выводит ошибку синтаксиса.

---

**2**.  Если пишут так:

> composer config -g github-oauth.github.com мой_токен

то как бы команда проходит, но ничего не происходит , даже если выполнить команды:

> composer install
>
> composer update

---

**3**. Если пишу так:

> composer config github-oauth.github.com мой_токен

То создаётся файл **auth.json**, где записан сам токен.

**Вопрос**: Подскажите, почему не работает так как написанно в оффициальной документации, то есть, так:

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <мой_токен>
   или
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com мой_токен
```

Answer (score 1):

В документации приведены команды для глобально установленного композера, на это указывает параметр `-g` в командах.

Стрелочки не надо вводить, они означают параметр, который нужно заменить, поэтому введенная команда должна выглядеть так:

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com abc543785qwerwe
```